# My form fields turn to mandatory after form submit?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

After I submit the form successfully, form fields turn to required again. Note that page is not refreshed on submit but the form is reset.
      [image: Error Image]

```
<form #contactUsForm>                        
    <mat-form-field>
     <input type="text" matInput 
      (blur)="nameValidate()" [(ngModel)]="_userName" name="uName" required>
    </mat-form-field>    

   <mat-form-field>
    <input type="email" matInput [(ngModel)]="_userEmail" name="uEmail" 
      (blur)="emailValidate()" required>
   </mat-form-field>                      

   <div>
    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit();contactUsForm.reset()"  
       mat-raised-button>Submit </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Is anything wrong with event firing ??

Comment: because you're calling `reset()`

Comment: You can add a check whether form field is dirty.

Comment: @ Roopesh Kumar Ramesh- whats the solution?How can i clear form fileds without reset() ?

Comment: Please share stackblitz code. will check

Comment: https://angular-tp6sfw.stackblitz.io/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tp6sfw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontact-us%2Fcontact-us.component.html

Comment: stackblitz working fine

Comment: its fine in stackblitz. may be bcz its not taking animations of mat-input when field is required